# Gibt es ein eigenes Wort für beschmutztes Geschirr?

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es ein eigenes Wort für beschmutztes Geschirr?

Zum Beispiel:

> "Du hast zu viel ____ in deinem Zimmer!"

Comment: Die Antworten zeigen, dass die richtige Antwort nicht zwangsläufig demokratisch ermittelt werden kann, Abwasch ist voll im Ausguss gelandet.

Comment: Man könnte von "Schmutzwäsche" (gängig) zu "Schmutzgeschirr" (Neologismus) gehen. Verstanden würde man. Im konkreten Kontext stellt sich mir die Frage, ob "Geschirr" nicht ausreicht.

Comment: Rührt diese Frage von einer Sprache, in der es ein solches Wort gibt?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Das, was du am häufigsten hören wirst, ist entweder „*dreckiges Geschirr*“ oder „*schmutziges Geschirr*“. Daher ist „*Du hast zu viel dreckiges Geschirr in deinem Zimmer!*“ völlig in Ordnung.

Ich persönlich habe noch nie ein spezielles Wort dafür gehört, aber ich wäre nicht überrascht, wenn es eines gäbe.

---

What you will be hearing the most time would be either *“dreckiges Geschirr”* or *“schmutziges Geschirr”*. So using *“Du hast zu viel dreckiges Geschirr in deinem Zimmer!”* is just fine.

Personally I never heard a special word for it, although I wouldn’t be surprised if there was one.

Comment: Ich kenne die Kurzform / I know the short form *Schmutzgeschirr*.

Answer (score 18):

Ein einzelnes Wort für „schmutziges Geschirr“ oder „dreckiges Geschirr“ ist „Abwasch“. Aber in dem Kontext des Satzes würde ich das so nicht verwenden, sondern die Variante aus zwei Wörtern wählen.

Comment: Abwasch wird in Sachsen-Anhalt dafür auch verwendet. Ist wohl ein Regionalismus.

Comment: Ich dachte immer, der Abwasch sei die substantivierte Tätigkeit, das abwaschen.

Comment: Ich hab Abwasch auch schon gelesen.  Oder gehört?  Auf jeden Fall ist es [hier](http://karlsruhe.de) bei Einheimischen nicht gebräuchlich (okay, die reden sowieso Badisch, den "die" können bekanntlich alles, ausser Hochdeutsch :D)

Comment: Vom "Abwasch" höre ich hier in Brandenburg häufig, allerdings nur dann, wenn er dort ist, wo er "hingehört": auf/in der Spüle zum Beispiel. Dann muss auch irgendwann der "Abwasch" gemacht oder "abgewaschen" werden.Ansonsten ist es das (umgangssprachliche) "dreckige Geschirr".

Comment: Wenn ich „den Abwasch mache“, produziere ich aber kein dreckiges Geschirr, sondern ganz im Gegenteil reduziere es. Und „Du hast zu viel Abwasch in Deinem Zimmer.“ klingt auch irgendwie falsch... :)

Comment: Die Bezeichnung 'Abwasch' ist auch mir bekannt, aber es umfasst nicht unbedingt nur schmutziges Geschirr. Mit 'Abwasch' kann generell alles Geschirr gemeint sein, das sich im Prozess des Abwaschens befindet, also auch das bereits gereinigte Geschirr im Ablagekorb. Ich sehe das analog zu 'Wäsche' bei Kleidung/Textilien. Man könnte dementsprechend auch einfach Schmutzgeschirr sagen - klingt etwas nach Spüliwerbung, aber geht doch?

Comment: »**Die Abwasch**« (weiblich) ist in Österreich das Spülbecken, in dem das Geschirr abgewaschen wird. (»*Bitte stell das schmutzige Geschirr in die Abwasch*«). »**Der Abwasch**« (männlich) ist in Österreich der Vorgang bei dem das Geschirr abgewaschen wird. »Den Abwasch machen« bedeutet daher, dass man diesen Vorgang durchführt. Andere Bedeutungen hat das Wort in Österreich nicht, insbesondere wird es hierzulande *NICHT* als Bezeichnung für schmutziges Geschirr verwendet.

Answer (score 14):

Aufwasch wäre so ein Wort. Siehe auch: [Aufwasch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Aufwasch)

Comment: Nie gehört (jedenfalls nicht in diesem Sinne). Vielleicht regional begrenzt?

Comment: @balpha: Ich hab das Wort auch nie in dem Kontext genutzt und würde auch "Schmutziges Geschirr" wählen, allerdings scheint Aufwasch doch richtig zu sein und die Frage war nach einem Wort.

Comment: Das Wort ist hier (Kölner Raum) ebenfalls nicht gebräuchlich.

Comment: Auch in Berlin (west) nur im Rahmen der Wendung "in einem Aufwasch" bekannt.

Comment: Das _Variantenwörterbuch_ gibt, für diese Bedeutung, „D-mittel/nord“ an. Ich habe es aber auch noch nie gehört.

Answer (score 7):

"Schmutziges Geschirr" dürfte die wohl üblichste Wortwahl sein.

Comment: Im gegebenen Kontext ist es wahrscheinlicher, dass "dreckig" verwendet wird, da es etwas abwertender ist.

Answer (score 4):

Ich kenne tatsächlich eine Reihe von Leuten, die schmutziges Geschirr einfach als "Spül" bezeichnen.

Ein Aufruf wie "Kannst du mal das schmutzige Geschirr saubermachen" wird dann zu "Kannst du mal den Spül erledigen".

Keine Ahnung wie verbreitet das ganze ist ;-)

Answer (score 3):

"Du hast zu viel Abwasch in deinem Zimmer!" (ungewöhnlich)

Eher noch: "[Den Abwasch machen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abwasch)" heißt dann so viel wie "Spülen".

Answer (score 1):

Ich kenne nur die Bezeichnung *schmutzige(s) Teller/Gläser/Geschirr/...*.