# "Abwaschen" vs. "aufwaschen"

Tags: etymology, verb, prefix

Ich habe mir hin und wieder schon die Frage gestellt, woher die unterschiedliche Benutzung von ["ab-"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abwaschen) und ["aufwaschen"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufwaschen) für die Tätigkeit des spülens von Geschirr kommt.

Im folgenden Ngram kann man sehen, dass "Abwasch" erst seit den 1940er Jahren einen Vorsprung vor "Aufwasch" gewinnt. "[A]bwaschen" in der nicht substantivierten Form hat, wahrscheinlich aufgrund der weiteren Bedeutungen, einen deutlichen Vorsprung, gewinnt aber anscheinend auch darüber hinaus (nach dem letzten Gipfel, als wir uns nach dem zweiten Weltkrieg alle Schuld zur Genüge abgewaschen hatten) gegenüber "aufwaschen".
[image: Google Ngram bezüglich "Abwasch", "Aufwasch", "abwaschen" und "aufwaschen"]

Ich konnte zur Etymologie nichts finden, was auf diesen Unterschied eingeht. Im Englischen zum Beispiel kenne ich nur "washing-up", was dummerweise wegen der Homophonie ein falscher Freund zu "abwaschen" sein könnte, aber von der Bedeutung eher "aufwaschen" entspricht. - Könnte darin - und in der Tatsache, dass der Siegeszug von "abwaschen" erst nach dem Krieg 
so richtig begonnen zu haben scheint - schon die Lösung liegen?

Comment: Slightly related: [Gibt es ein eigenes Wort für beschmutztes Geschirr?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/38/1224)

Comment: Für mich heisst es übrigens einzig *abwaschen* oder *abspülen* oder *den Spül machen*, aber niemals *aufwaschen*. Und entsprechend *to wash up* == *abwaschen* ;)

Comment: @Em1 Das war die Frage, die mich wieder mal darauf stieß... ;)

Comment: Den Spül? Du meinst die Spüle?

Comment: Wo stammt denn das Ngram her? Von Google? Dann sind das erstens nur gedruckte Texte (also keine Aussage über gesprochene Sprache) und zweitens nur der Corpus von Google Books. Die Frage ist also, welche Relevanz diese Grafik eigentlich besitzt.

Answer (score 5):

Von der Bedeutung her sind beide Wörter gleich.

"Aufwasch" wird vor allem in Sachsen genutzt, "Abwasch" im restlichen Sprachraum: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r10-f8a/

(Ich bin selbst Sachse und nutze nur "aufwaschen")

Answer (score 4):

Aus der Grafik erfahren wir ja nun leider nichts über die Bedeutung der jeweiligen Verwendungen. Ältere Wörterbücher (Grimm, Adelung usw.) geben in etwa folgende Bedeutungen für die beiden Wörter an:

**abwaschen** 1. durch Waschen wegbringen (den Schmutz abwaschen [Achtung: Hier wir der Schmutz abgewaschen, nicht das Geschirr!]) 2. wegspülen, wegschwemmen (der Regen wäscht die Erde vom Ufer ab) 3. durch Waschen bezahlen

**aufwaschen** 1.durch Waschen reinigen, z.B. Küchengeschirr 2. mit Wasser vom Boden auffassen (Blut aufwaschen) 3. wund waschen (die Hände aufwaschen) 4. durch Waschen verbrauchen (die Seife aufwaschen) 4. lebendig waschen ("sie hätte sich gar gern mit fremdem blut zum leben wieder aufgewaschen", Goethe)

Die Bedeutung ergibt sich schlichtweg aus der Bedeutung der Vorsilben ab- bzw. auf-.

Aufwasch kenne und empfinde ich gebräuchlich besonders im Zusammenhang mit Aufräumen und hat dann die Bedeutung "das Geschirr reinigen um Ordnung zu schaffen". Zur Illustration: Nach dem Aufwaschen ist in der Küche alles verräumt, nach dem Abwasch steht es zum Abtropfen im Geschirrständer.

Das muss nun natürlich nicht jeder Sprecher so verwenden, aber da für uns alle durch andere Worte mit den Präfixen ab- und auf- der Ab- bzw. Aufwasch eine bestimmte Konnotation erhalten, könnte es sein, dass die beiden Worte eben nicht ganz synonym sind sondern je nach Zusammenhang bevorzugt verwendet werden könnten.

Im Übrigen wurde nach dem Krieg die massenmediale Werbung für Spülmittel und dann auch für die Spülmaschine eingeführt, wodurch sich eine "Standardisierung" ergeben haben könnte. Man müsste die historische Werbesprache untersuchen um festzustellen, ob sie, wie ich vermute, die Worte Abwasch und abwaschen bevorzugt und damit zu ihrer Verbreitung beigetragen hat.

Answer (score 3):

**Abwaschen:**
Entfernen (*ab*-machen) von Schmutz durch Waschen.
Man kann einen schmutzigen Gegenstand *abwaschen*. Vorher war Schmutz an dem Gegenstand, und der wird durch das Waschen "abgemacht", also entfernt. Ein Gegenstand, der *abwaschbar* ist, hat eine feste, stabile Form, kann leicht mit der Hand bewegt werden und gefahrlos unter fließendes Wasser gehalten werden. Man kann also Geschirr *abwaschen* aber auch einen Ball, einen Hammer und sogar eine Schallplatte. Ein "richtiges" Auto kann man nicht so einfach mit der Hand bewegen, daher kann man es zwar *waschen*, aber nicht *abwaschen*. Eine Hose hat keine stabile Form, daher wird auch eine Hose gewaschen aber nicht abgewaschen.

**Abspülen:**
Hat zwei Bedeutungen:
1) Synonym für "abwaschen".
2) Spülen mit klarem Wasser (ohne Reinigungsmittel) nach dem eigentlichen Reinigungsvorgang um das Reinigungsmittel zu entfernen.

**Aufwaschen:**
Kenne ich nur als Bezeichnung für die Reinigung eines Fußbodens mit viel Wasser: "Klaus sollte morgen mal den Boden der Küche aufwaschen". Wenn Klaus das macht, schüttet er Wasser und Reinigungsmittel auf den Boden, verteilt es mit einem Mop und wischt dann das schmutzige Wasser mit dem Mop wieder auf oder wischt es in einen Abfluss.

**Aufwischen**
Wenn es um einen Fußboden geht: Wie "aufwaschen", aber mit weniger Wasser (nicht nass, sondern nur feucht). Man kann aber auch verschüttete Flüssigkeiten von ebenen Flächen (Boden, Tisch, Arbeitsplatte, usw.) aufwischen.

Comment: Habe in meine Frage Links zu den Duden-Definitionen beider Verben eingefügt, um das Nachschlagen zu vereinfachen. Dort steht auch, dass "aufwaschen" in Österreich und "landschaftlich" (hat Österreich keine Landschaft?) für "wischen, feucht reinigen" steht und _nur_ "landschaftlich" für "spülen, abwaschen".

Comment: Abwaschen agree, Aufwischen agree. Man könnte der Vollständigkeit zur Liebe noch *auswaschen* hinzufügen (womit du die Hose dann auch abgedeckt hättest)

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Hahaha... Nein, Österreich hat keine Landschaft ;) [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/landschaftlich#Bedeutung2) oder besser [wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/landschaftlich). Das bedeutet übrigens: Abwaschen ist Standarddeutsch. Aufwaschen gilt für einige Regionen. (Wo ich den Westen mal ausschließe, sonst würde ich es kennen)

Comment: @Em1 Also ist "österreichisch" in ganz Österreich verbreitet, "landschaftlich" aber nur landschaftlich, möglicherweise auch in Teilen Österreichs? - Was wäre dann das Gegenstück zu "österreichisch" für Deutschland?  - Oder ist "landschaftlich" immer auf Deutschland beschränkt und "österreichisch" heißt es auch, wenn es nur Teile Österreichs betrifft? - Oder noch anders? - Und ich muss mal wieder nach Österreich: Das letzte Mal, als ich dort war, hatten sie noch Landschaft... ;)

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Gute Frage. Ich denke, dass das ganze System nicht so tiefgreifend ist. Es gibt - denke ich - kein "landschaftlich österreichisch". Und auch ein "nur Deutsch" gibt es nicht. Sieh mal [Kartoffel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kartoffel), dort findest du die Ösi-Bezeichnung als Synonym.